# Lyx to pdflatex: No information for exporting the format

Tags: pdftex, lyx, export

I have a .lyx file that I'd like to have in pdflatex format. However, when I choose File->Export->Export as and choose for "Save as type" "LaTeX (pdflatex)", LyX gives me a cryptic error "Couldn't export file" with a message "No information for exporting the format LaTeX (pdflatex)."

Any ideas what information LyX might need for this export?

I am using Lyx version 2.2.3.

Comment: Install LyX does not install necessarily LaTeX. Have you installed first LaTeX? Have you installed LaTeX atter LyX *and* reconfigure  LyX in the "Tools" menu?

Comment: I have Miktex installed and it was installed before I installed Lyx. The reconfigure tool seems to have no effect.

Comment: 2.2.3 is an old version. I suggest trying the latest release of LyX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this was a duplicate of [Lyx cannot output to pdflatex for a specific file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231655/lyx-cannot-output-to-pdflatex-for-a-specific-file?rq=1). See the accepted answer there for a solution.